# how to encode "@" special character in username parameter of FROM and TO header URI in PJSIP library while sending REGISTER message?

Tags: objective-c, pjsip

I'm developing iOS app with using of PJSIP. I want to send register message through PJSIP. I have **@** in username, for example **nandha@gmail.com** .

I encoded **@** as **%40** and added account **username** as nandha%40gmail.com and **SIP URL** as sip:nandha%40gmail.com@142.23.16.20:2020

I passed the username and sip url into PJSIP. Account is added successfully, but it can't send any REGISTER Message to the server.

I think it has added the encoded username and sip url. when sending register message it decoded the value as **nandha@gmail.com@142.23.16.20:2020** and it takes  IP PORT value after **@** symbol, like as **gmail.com@142.23.16.20:2020**

why PJSIP not sending the REGISTER message while encoding username?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, PJSIP automatically decode the Encoded characters while separating the username@sipIP:port

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it by two way,

**First**

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<sip:%s@%s:%s;transport=%s>", number, server, port, transport] UTF8String];
```

**Second**

```
pj_ansi_snprintf(acc_cfg.id.ptr, PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE, "<sip:%s@%s;transport=%s>", uname, server, transport);
```

Comment: I know how to delimit the sip URI<sip:username@ip:port>, but In case of containing "@" special character within the username, how could you delimit and just check username with a special character to PJSIP while registration. It doesn't register because it doesn't know how to delimit and PJSIP doesn't support username with a special character. If you find out a solution for this problem, please specify below. Then sure, I'll accept as an answer.